# Replace ampersand in URL with "and"

Tags: java, spring, web

I'm a bit new to Spring and trying to replace my parameters to pass as key:value pairs and also replace an ampersand with a literal "and" to avoid issues when hitting the screen. Example:

I want to go from: `mySite/myPage.html?myId=154933680&myRequest='QT'`

to have a separate method/entrypoint that will work like this:
`myPage?search=myId=154735535 and myRequest="RT"`

Now, my current header looks like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "myPage.html", method = RequestMethod.GET) public ModelAndView getSite(HttpServletRequest request, @RequestParam String myId, @RequestParam String myRequest)
```

I'm trying to do something like this instead, but its not working:

```
  @RequestMapping(value = "myPage?search=", method = RequestMethod.GET) public ModelAndView mySearch(HttpServletRequest request, @RequestParam String myId, @RequestParam String myRequest) {
```

But I would like to pass in them as key:value params rather than straight Strings as well. I'm a little all over the place here, I guess my main question would be with what I have above, how do I swap my URL to not string the parameters together with a "&" but to use "and" instead?

Comment: What is "issues when hitting the screen"?

Comment: Sorry - should have elaborated, it seems the issue is that if I log out and log back in, the & will cut off the second parameter so I will only get myId, not myRequest as well, which will cause an error. So I wanted a way to escape the "&" if possible.

Comment: I don't think that problem has anything to do with default url parameter formatting.

Comment: The way to escape the & in an URL is to  use `%26` instead,  otherwise it‘s considered a separator for query-params

Comment: Why could you not keep the parameters as-is? That's a pretty standard approach for these types of values, you'd just have a third parameter: `?type=search&myId=154...&myRequest='RT'`. If you're truly wanting to pass data as a query parameter _value_, you'd have to be sure to URL-encode it, via `URLEncoder#encode`.

Comment: I think my issue is that I need the URL to look the way it does in the second one above (search=myid=<id>&myRequest=<>). But since I'm trying to assign them all to a search param it is mixing them up? Is there a way I can assign to a hash map the values of search, one key being myId and the other being myRequest?

Comment: My point is you could map them the exact same way, putting all of the parameters into a `Map`, by introducing `search` as a third parameter instead (e.g. to determine what method to use). If you go the route of URL encoding the values you're passing, then you'll end up with a single `String` of that data, which you'll need to URL decode, parse yourself, and _then_ put in a Map.